# When I try to install mysql-server I get an error telling me i need mysql-community-server

Tags: package-management, mysql

When I run:

```
sudo apt -i install mysql-server
```

I get an error telling me there is an unmet dependency for: 'mysql-community-server is missing'

I tried this solution from a similar question but it did not work:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-community-server
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install mysql-server"
```

How do I get this to install?

I am using MySQL 5.7 and Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I have installed earlier in my system and it didn't show any issues.

```
user $ apt-cache depends mysql-server
mysql-server
 Depends: mysql-server-5.7
```

It only showed mysql-server-5.7 
Try these links:
[digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: using that process still fails to install.

error message: Process: 6816 ExecStartPre = /usr/shr/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exit ed status =1 /faiure)

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure)
installed mysql-server 5.7 package post-installation script sub-process returned error exit status = 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however
package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

Answer (score 0):

turns out that for the time being this won't work with the latest version of python and this version of MySQL. I eventually set up an environment using another service and will re-visit this later